# NSOperation fails on execution

Tags: ios, multithreading, ios7, nsoperation

1. I have problem with NSOperations. Everything works fine but sometimes (I don't know why) Operation block is simply skipped. Am I missing something? How is it possible that operation is not even NSLogging "operation entered"? Here is some code from viewDidLoad:

   ```
   //I'm using weakOperation in order to make [self.queue cancelAllOperation] method when viewWillDisappear

   NSBlockOperation* operation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
   __weak NSBlockOperation* weakOperation = operation;

   NSString *session=@"";
   @try{
       session = [self getSessionId];//getting data from CoreData

   }@catch(NSException *e)
   {
       NSLog(@"EXCEPTION WITH SESSION");
   }

   weakOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
       NSLog(@"operation entered");
       [self downloadJSONArray]; //doing some connection downloading and using session
       [self downloadImages]; //downloading images from urls from JSONs
       [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
           [self refresh]; //update mainThread 
       }
   }

   [self.queue addOperation:weakOperation];
   ```

   What could be scenario that coul make skip this block ?
2. Is there max number of threads created in iOS?

**EDIT**: Hey, I'have found why this happends - when a lot of applications run in the background and iOS does not have resources to queue another thread it simply skips that, how to behave in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning a new `NSBlockOperation` to a weak variable. Whenever you assign a new object to a weak variable, you risk having it released immediately.

If you needed a weak reference to the operation, you'd assign the object to some local variable first, and then get the weak reference for that object:

```
NSBlockOperation* operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"operation entered");
    [self downloadJSONArray]; //doing some connection downloading and using session
    [self downloadImages]; //downloading images from urls from JSONs
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self refresh]; //update mainThread 
    }
}

__weak NSBlockOperation* weakOperation = operation;

[self.queue addOperation:weakOperation];
```

But, as the method stands, the `weakOperation` is unnecessary. You generally only need weak references to avoid strong reference cycles. But no such cycle is present currently, so you can just do:

```
NSBlockOperation* operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"operation entered");
    [self downloadJSONArray]; //doing some connection downloading and using session
    [self downloadImages]; //downloading images from urls from JSONs
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self refresh]; //update mainThread 
    }
}

[self.queue addOperation:operation];
```

---

Looking at your code comment, you say "I'm using `weakOperation` in order to make `[self.queue cancelAllOperation]` method when `viewWillDisappear`". Using `weakOperation` like this will not accomplish what you want because your operation is not checking to see if it was canceled and thus it will not respond when the `NSOperationQueue` tries to cancel it.

If you wanted to do that, then a variation on your `weakOperation` pattern can be useful, but rather than using this `weakOperation` to add it to the queue, you can use the weak reference within the block to check to see if the operation was canceled (and you want the weak reference in the block to avoid the block from retaining the operation, itself, causing a strong reference cycle). The other key observation is that rather than creating a new `NSBlockOperation`, simply add an execution block to the original operation you created:

```
NSBlockOperation* operation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
__weak NSBlockOperation* weakOperation = operation;

[operation addExecutionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"operation entered");

    if ([weakOperation isCancelled]) return;

    [self downloadJSONArray]; //doing some connection downloading and using session

    if ([weakOperation isCancelled]) return;

    [self downloadImages]; //downloading images from urls from JSONs

    if ([weakOperation isCancelled]) return;

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self refresh]; //update mainThread
    }];
}];

[self.queue addOperation:operation];
```

Clearly, if the operation is tied up in `downloadJSONArray` or `downloadImages`, it won't respond to the cancelation event until it returns from those methods. You'd have to check the cancelation status with those methods, too, if you want this operation to respond reasonably quickly to the cancellation event.

---

In answer to your second question, yes, there is a maximum number of threads, but it's a reasonably large number and there are other factors that come into play before the number of threads becomes an issue. The constraining factor is likely to be the `downloadImages` method (as you can only have 5 concurrent download requests). And even if that wasn't an issue, you'd want to constrain the number of concurrent operations, anyway, to mitigate the app's peak memory usage. If there are any network operations involved, you generally want to do something like:

```
self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;  // or 5
```

That way, you minimize how much of the limited system resources (including threads) you are using.

By the way, I assume that `downloadJSONArray` and `downloadImages` are synchronous methods. If those are performing asynchronous network requests, you might want to consider further refactoring of the code to ensure the operation doesn't complete prematurely (e.g. wrap this in a concurrent `NSOperation` subclass or change those methods to run synchronously).

Comment: Hey, so what is better if we have this maximum number of thread limitation? Have one big async thread/nsoperation or couple of small onces ?

Comment: I'd first focus on getting the existing code to work as outlined above. Longer term, though, it's better to make the individual network requests separate operations, that way, when downloading the images, you can enjoy some concurrency and the concomitant performance gain that will yield. But this entails a significantly more radical refactoring of your code. But I'd be inclined to make an operation for downloading the JSON, have that then create the individual download operations for the images, and then make the final `refresh` operation dependent upon the image operations.

Comment: That way, it will not only download images faster but it will also be more responsive to `cancelAllOperations`. If you use `maxConcurrentOperationCount`, it eliminates concerns about max number of threads (or more importantly, max number of concurrent network requests). As an aside, you might alternatively want to update the UI as each image download finishes, that way the user will get some sense of progress and the downloads are in progress. It depends upon the desired UX.

Comment: Hey Rob, I see that you are an expert of NSOperations, could you please tell me one last thing - if we didn't set maxConcurrentOperationCount there would be default number depending on current resources, could this number be 0? It will make sense why my operation didn't work. And what would be the behaviour of ios, if we set maxConcurrentOperationCount to 4, then called new NSOperation  even if we don't have resources to do this? Thank you master! :)

Comment: IMHO, the max number of threads is not really a material issue in a situation like this (and is unlikely to be the source of your issue). The bigger issue the number of network requests that can run concurrently. There's no point in starting a 100 image download requests if it can only perform 5 at a time (and risk having the latter requests timeout). And even if you could do that many concurrent network requests, you wouldn't want to, because that would be an extravagant use of memory. Bottom line, don't tie up system resources starting a network request that can't possibly be satisfied.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzpyrka By the way, if you're downloading images, you might want to consider the `UIImageView` categories in [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). Either one will do the asynchronous image loading for you (which makes your life easier), it will employ lazy loading of the images (load them as the UI needs them), it will handle the cancelation of the requests as the view controller is dismissed, etc. No need to reinvent the wheel here...

Comment: Yeah I agree and totally understand you, I'm just wondering if I download images one by one in for() loop and update UI in loop block (in mainQueue once every image was downloaded) could cause this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57778/discussion-between-rob-and-lukasz-szpyrka).

Comment: That's quite a claim and certainly not one that I can reconcile with my experience. There's a saying that extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence: I'd suggest that you post another question that provides a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstration of the behavior you describe. But I find it very hard to believe that you're unable to have the operation queue provide the five worker threads that your app needs.